# "in comparison with" used with a comparative adjective

Tags: comparison

I'm wondering if it is idiomatic to use a comparative adjective with "in comparison":

> In comparison with Joe, Peter is much wealthier.

There is the issue of collocation; "in comparison" and a comparative adjective seem redundant together. "than sb./sth." seems more suited to go with a comparative adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to use a comparative adjective here. You need a comparison, so this is a good way to do so.
Another way is, as explained in the comments by rjpond, 'In comparison with Peter, Joe is poor', where no comparative adjective is used.

Comment: I agree that it's correct to use one, but I don't agree that it's necessary.  To me "In comparison with Joe, Peter is very wealthy" and "In comparison with Peter, Joe is poor" are absolutely fine.

Comment: @rjpond Huh so obvious, yet when I was thinking about it it seemed clear as day that is was necessary - let me edit edit my answer.

Comment: @rjpond   Don't you think "in comparison" and a comparative adjective seem redundant together? "than sb./sth." seems more suited to go with a comparative adjective. –

Comment: @Apollyon I understand your point, but your original sentence (with the comparative) didn't strike me as unidiomatic.